Homology of the quotient space by group action and $C_*$ preserving homotopy pushouts
Let $G$ be a Lie group, $E$ is a principle $G$-bundle and $X$ a topological space with right action of $G$. We have pushout diagram in the category of topological spaces
\begin{array}
A X \times G \times E & \stackrel{a_X \times 1_E}{\longrightarrow} & X \times E \\
\downarrow{1_X \times a_E} & & \downarrow{} \\
X \times E & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & X \times_G E  
\end{array}
The singular chains complex $C_*(G)$ is a dg-algbera with Pontryagin product, $C_*(X)$ is a right $C_*(G)$-module and $C_*(E)$ is a left $C_*(G)$-module.  Moore's theorem states that $C_*(X \times_G E) \cong C_*(X) \otimes^{\mathbb{L}}_{C_*(G)} C_*(E)$. The proof of this theorem is not trivial.
But categorically this is a statemnt that functor $C_*$ maps pushout to the homotopy pushout (derived tensor product). Can it be proved by
(i) noticing that functor $C_*$ maps homotopy pushouts to homotopy pushouts,
(ii) assumption that $E$ is a principle $G$-bundle imply that pushout that we consider is equivalent to the homotopy pushout?
